# in app purchaise add binary

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I have submit new version of app and new in app Purchase. Apple have accent new version of app but not accept in app Purchase.

In-App Purchase - New Business Model

We have begun the review of your In-App Purchase(s) but aren't able to continue because your submitted In-App Purchase(s) indicate a change of business model for your app. Therefore, we need to verify the implementation of your submitted In-App Purchase(s) in the app to ensure your app, and its In-App Purchase(s), are in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Next Steps

Please upload a new binary for review and resubmit your In-App Purchase(s) with the binary so that we can continue the review.

I don't understand, I must only upload new build to itunes connect or then I must add build to in app Purchase?

Comment: how did u solve ur problem? facing d same issue...

Answer (score 7):

Steps that help me are:

1. You should remove your new In-App purchase.
2. Reject last app version (if it on Pending developer release state), or just create new version
3. Re-create In-App purchase again (I did it via Application loader (btw it's more usable than website itunesconnect.apple.com). Don't forget to add screenshot and languages (at least one - for example, English).
4. On itunesconnect.apple.com at the page of your prepared for submit version, you can find In-App purchases section (that was hided before)
5. Click on "+" - and add your re-created in-app purchase
6. Upload binary and submit for review
7. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if they write about different model, than you must re-check types of your in-app purchases.

May be the means that your application must fulfill with their business models, so for example, I think, you can't create paid application with subscription. 
Btw, refer to this [model descriptions](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/business-models/)

After that simply create new build and don't forget *to attach in-app* to it before review