# New adds in App purchases gets rejected

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have a problem submiting  a new in-app purchases for my app. I already have in-app purchases but when i try to add a new one, i got a new message that says:

"Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase

We have begun the review of your in-app purchases but aren't able to continue because your submitted in-app purchases indicate a change of business model for your app. Therefore, we need to verify the implementation of your submitted in-app purchases in the app to ensure your app, and its in-app purchases, are in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Next Steps

Please upload a new binary for review and resubmit your in-app purchases with the binary so that we can continue the review.

"

I already have upload a new binary and resubmit my in-app purchases but again appear the same message. Does anyone know what could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps that might help you:

1) You should remove your new In-App purchase.

2) Reject last app version (if it on Pending developer release state), or just create new version

3) Re-create In-App purchase again (I did it via Application loader (btw it's more usable than website itunesconnect.apple.com). Don't forget to add screenshot and languages (at least one - for example, English).

4) On itunesconnect.apple.com at the page of your prepared for submit version, you can find In-App purchases section (that was hided before)

5) Click on "+" - and add your re-created in-app purchase

6) Upload binary and submit for review

7) Enjoy!

Original Source [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42362865/7956211)